# Consolidate RequireJS Shim definition across multiple configurations

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using RequireJS in a large application. I also make use of the optimization tool to optimize/minify my code.

I have my data-main file, Main.js. In this file, I define a set of shims:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    shim: {
        "libs/shimmedLibrary": {
            deps: ["libs/blah"],
            exports: "shimmedLibrary"
        }
    }
});
```

In addition, I also have my buildconfig.js file, which defines the optimization parameters:

```
({
    baseUrl: "../js",
    shim: {
        "libs/shimmedLibrary": {
            deps: ["libs/blah"],
            exports: "shimmedLibrary"
        }
    },
    include: ["requireLib"],
    name: "js/Main",
    out: "../bin/js/Main-built.js",
    optimize: "none"
})
```

Looking at these two configurations, one can see that the `shim` object is identical in both files. This creates a bit of a headache because if I ever have to add in a `shim` object, I have to MAKE SURE that I add the shim reference in both configuration files.  In reality, my shim object actually contains about a dozen shims, so this makes maintenance a bit of a pain.

Is there any way for me to create a single, shared reference to my `shim` object such that both my data-main Main.js file, and my optimization buildconfig.js file can both re-use that same reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`mainConfigFile`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27) option in your build config so that it points to the file that contains your runtime configuration:

```
mainConfigFile: "js/Main.js"
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something easy I overlooked. Thanks.